# IntelliJ IDEA error introspecting MySQL schema with dashes in tables names

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I have some tables with dashes in their names, like aaa_2021-06-12_2021-06-18, so when I try to introspect schema (click Refresh) IntelliJ IDEA says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-06-12_2021-06-18' at line 1.

I guess it queries tables names without backticks `. Are there some workarounds?

Comment: What is the version of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Try 2022.2, where similar bugs were fixed

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. My current version is IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)